# Syntax error with parameterized queries after switching from pyodbc to pymssql

Tags: python-2.7, sql-server-2008, pyodbc, pymssql, executemany

I have **13-15MB** raw files to load its data into DB, and it takes around **50-55mins** to insert around **30k-35k** rows using executemany with pyodbc and it worked fine but its processing time is high.

For testing the performance I tried pymssql but it is showing syntax error here

```
x = [('a',1),('b',2).... ]  # inserting only 999 rows at a time
qry = "INSERT INTO ["+tablename+"] VALUES({}) ".format(placeholders)
cursor.executemany(qry,x)

print qry
 # INSERT INTO [my_T] VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?...)
```

AT executemany() it is thowing error as

Error:

> Error in loadData (102, "Incorrect syntax near '?'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n"

Comment: What are the `placeholders`?

Comment: those are (?,?,....) are around 89 columns.. the same syntax worked with pyodbc

Comment: For pymssql you will need to change the placeholders from `?` to `%s`.

Comment: @GordThompson Great thanks it solved my problem,Thanks again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's [DB-API 2.0](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) specification defines several [parameter styles](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) that implementers can use.

pyodbc adopted the "qmark" style which is the most common style for ODBC

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)
```

while pymssql opted for the "format" style

```sql
INSERT INTO tablename (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)
```

Note that for historical reasons pymssql supports `%d` as well as `%s` but we don't need to use `%s` for strings and `%d` for numbers; `%s` works in all cases and is the preferred placeholder.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination